# Use JavaScript to validate input for the two search boxes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, alert

I only want to use js for validation. The name box should accept no more than 20 characters and not accept numbers. The currency code box should only accept three upper case letters A-Z. The search button for each box should display a pop-up message with country names and currencies of all matches (up to 5)

I tried making it so that the country is the key, currency is the value
and i would just need to print out the key name and the value of that key, and used event listeners to validate/display the results and an alert function for wrong input.
Nothing is working so far, i'm not sure if i'm doing it the wrong way or if its another error.
This is my html code for the search boxes:

```
<div class="search-box">
    <label for="name">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    <button id="name-search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>

<!-- Second Search Box: Search by Currency -->
<div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" id="currency" name="currency" placeholder="Enter code">
    <button id="currency-search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

**This is my js code**

```
var countriesData = {
    "Afghanistan": "AFN",
    "Brazil": "BRL",
    "Canada":"CAD",
    "Germany":"EUR", 
     "Libya": "LYD", 
     "Mexico": "MXN",
     "Morocco": "MAD",
     "Pakistan": "PKR",  
     "Romania": "RON",  
     "Spain": "EUR", 
     "Zambia": "ZMK",
     "Zimbabwe": "ZWD",
     "Sudan": "SDG",
     "Serbia": "RSD",
     "Samoa": "EUR",
     "Portugal": "EUR",
     "Saudi Arabia": "SAR",
     "Somalia": "SOS",
     "Philippines": "PHP",
     "Norway": "NOK"
};

function performSearch(inputElement, resultsElement) {
    const searchValue = inputElement.value.trim();
    const results = [];

    // Validate and search for matches based on the inputElement's ID
    if (inputElement.id === "name") {
        // Validate: No more than 20 characters and no numbers
        if (searchValue.length <= 20 && !/\d/.test(searchValue)) {
            for (const country in countriesData) {
                if (country.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())) {
                    results.push({ name: country, currency: countriesData[country] });
                    if (results.length >= 5) break; // Limit to 5 results
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (inputElement.id === "currency") {
        // Validate: Three upper case letters A-Z
        if (/^[A-Z]{3}$/.test(searchValue)) {
            for (const country in countriesData) {
                if (countriesData[country] === searchValue) {
                    results.push({ name: country, currency: searchValue });
                    if (results.length >= 5) break; // Limit to 5 results
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Display the results
    resultsElement.textContent = ""; // Clear previous results
    results.forEach(result => {
        const resultItem = document.createElement("p");
        resultItem.textContent = `${result.name} - Currency: ${result.currency}`;
        resultsElement.appendChild(resultItem);
    });
}

// Event listeners for search buttons
document.getElementById("name-search-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
    const resultsElement = document.getElementById("name-results");
    performSearch(nameInput, resultsElement);
});

document.getElementById("currency-search-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const currencyInput = document.getElementById("currency");
    const resultsElement = document.getElementById("currency-results");
    performSearch(currencyInput, resultsElement);
});
```

Comment: I saw no problem in the code. everything is working as expected. are you sure you are running it correctly? here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/arash__jb/pen/eYbyXXV